# Permission samba shared www folder

Tags: ubuntu, samba, apache-2.4, chmod, chown

I'm having trouble with permissions on a samba shared folder on ubuntu server 14.04.
This is the `www` one. But actually, it's in `/home/administrateur`.

As I want to preserve my `www` folder whatever happens, I put it in my `/home/administrateur` folder. For the permissions via `chmod`, I have 644 on files and 755 on folders. The owner is administrateur:administrateur.
I activated userdir mod in order to permit apache to load any site which is in `/home/administrateur/www`. And it works.
Now, I need this folder to be accessible from my windows network. So I added Samba.
I set it up like this :

```
[www]
    comment = Accès R/W/X pour tous
    path = /home/administrateur/www
    guest ok = Yes
    read only = No
    create mask = 644
    directory mask = 755
```

It shows in my network as expected, but when I try editing anything in it from my win 7, it says that I need to have an authorization from my `ubuntu-server\` administrator to modify is.

I dont want to give individual permissions, I want any machine in my network to be able to r/w/x what is shared by the ubuntu server.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you try editing the files on `ubuntu-server\` from a windows machine without using samba-credentials then you do this as **guest**. The guest-account itself has no permission to edit these files.

The persmissions should be 777 on files if you want r/w/x these files **without using samba-credentials of the ubuntu-server**.

**For security reasons you should always use the samba-credentials with r/w/x permission on the share. Setting files to 777 should only be done for test purposes.**

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the 777 return the same issue. I'm really stuck.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `ls -l home/administrator/`?

Comment: `drwxrwsrwx 10 administrateur users          4,0K mai   23 09:30 www`